# Does the Recommended Task Exception-Handling Code Synchronize the Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, task-parallel-library

It looks like the pattern on MSDN for handling exceptions raised in a Task synchronizes the code.  Here is the code from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx):

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    throw new MyCustomException("I'm bad, but not too bad!");
});    
try
{
    task1.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // Code removed
}
```

The call `task1.Wait();` causes the calling thread to block until task1 completes, right?  If so, then I don't see a reason for using a Task at all, because whether the code is called synchronously or asynchronously using a Task, the calling thread will block until either the code is finished running or an exception is thrown.

Also, what would happen if task1 throws an exception before the calling code enters the try-catch block?  If that is possible, the try-catch block will not catch the AggregateException.

What should I do if I want the calling thread to be notified of an exception raised in a Task?  I don't think I should have to call `task1.Wait();` in order to be notified of an exception.  I know about `ContinueWith()` but the code in `ContinueWith()` runs in a separate thread as well, not the calling thread.

Answer (score 3):

> The call task1.Wait(); causes the calling thread to block until task1
>   completes, right? If so, then I don't see a reason for using a Task at
>   all, because whether the code is called synchronously or
>   asynchronously using a Task, the calling thread will block until
>   either the code is finished running or an exception is thrown.

Right. But you can do whatever you need (e.g. start other tasks or perform some operations) on the calling thread before you call the `Wait()` method.

> Also, what would happen if task1 throws an exception before the
>   calling code enters the try-catch block? If that is possible, the
>   try-catch block will not catch the AggregateException.

The exception will be caught and stored internally. Then, when you call the `Wait()` method on a task instance, the original exception will be wrapped in `AggregateException` and propagated to the calling thread.

Comment: If my `task1` is a long-running task, or the amount of time to run the task is indeterminate, I will have no idea how many lines of code I'd need to fit in my try-catch block.  I'm looking for a more robust solution.  If I could hook an event handler up to the task that runs only when an exception happens, that would work.  I can do something like this with a BackgroundWorker, but I'd like to use a Task.

Comment: @user1214135 Are you looking for [`ContinueWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235663.aspx)?

Comment: @user1214135 You can set up a continuation using [`ContinueWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235663.aspx) (as @svick recommends), check [`Task.IsFaulted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted.aspx)/[`Task.Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) properties and, say, do something (show an error message?) on the UI thread using the [`Control.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) method.

Comment: @user1214135 Or, depending on your needs, you might prefer to use [`SynchronizationContext `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx31754f.aspx) or something else instead of [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx).

Comment: As I mentioned, I can't use a `ContinueWith()` because it runs on a separate thread as well. I can't use a `Control.Invoke` because my calling thread is not a GUI thread (I'm actually using a Console program). I tried using a `SynchronizationContext` but the `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null for me. I tried creating a `SynchronizationContext` but maybe I did it wrong.  When I pass it to the Task and then post a `SendOrPostCallback`, it runs on a third thread: the `ManagedThreadId`s are all different.